# Socket.io Client Not Receiving Data from Server Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, networking, socket.io

server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', { msg: 'world' });
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    console.log('That was a message from the client :)');
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('EDITED');
  document.write("test");
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
    //console.log(data);
    socket.emit('message', { msg: 'hello there server' });
  });
</script>
```

The server is accepting the message "hello there server" and displaying it correctly in the console;  However, when the server sends the message "hello" to the client, the client is supposed to give a pop up alert that should read "hello".  Instead of the pop up alert saying "hello", it says:  **[object Object]**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is an object:

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    alert(data.msg);
```

I'd consider using `console.log` when sending debug messages like this, as you can see the structure instead of just `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thanks Blender!  I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.  Are you like...the real Blender?

Comment: @nicktendo: The real blender?